# VB.NET - Save changes in Datagridview to DB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have set Oracle connection to DatagridView, via manager. Line for this is:

```
  Me.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MyDataSet._Users)
```

Now I want to save all changes made in Datagridview to DB. Tried this but not working:

```
 Me.UsersTableAdapter.Update(Me.MyDataSet._Users)
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Fabio, no error, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Correct synthax is:

```
Try
    Me.Validate()
    Me.UsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.UsersTableAdapter.Update(Me.MyDataSet._Users)
    MsgBox("Update successful")

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Update failed")
End Try
```

@the scion, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

1.Maybe you are missing `validate()` and `endEdit()` ?

```
Try
    Me.Validate()
    Me.UsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.UsersTableAdapter.Update(Me.MyDataSet._Users)
    MsgBox("Update successful")

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Update failed")
End Try
```

2. Do you have primary key for the table?

**Update**

Fix the code I present -

```
Me.UsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
```

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: thanks for link., It works now. But you've made a minor mistake, see my answer (EndEdit needs BindingSource, not TableAdapter).